# symfony 1.4.5 build-model error of duplicate table

Tags: symfony1, propel, symfony-1.4

i added a new mysql table and did a build-schema my config/schema.yml contains my new table
now when i run the build-model i get: 
Some problems occurred when executing the task:

```
build-propel.xml:474:20: Duplicate table found: propel.                                                                      

build-propel.xml:461:22: Execution of the target buildfile failed. Aborting.
```

If the exception message is not clear enough, read the output of the task for
  more information

how on earth must i find the duplicate table??
please help?
thank you

Comment: If you could provide the schema.yml that would help to find it out.

Comment: i heard that problem is because of the plugins using the shcema.yml file as they want, in a not-compatible way with the propel:build --model task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had this problem before. It is due to any schema.xml files lying around in your config folder. Try deleting these and run the command again.

Answer (score 0):

a duplicate **schema.yml** or **generated-schema.xml** exists somewhere in your plugins, rename it to schema.yml.back or delete it. [reference](https://webpowered.tumblr.com/?amp_see_more=1)